# Hibernate Batch Insert with Spring and Hibernate not working

Tags: hibernate

I'm having trouble getting Hibernate to perform a bulk insert on MySQL.

I have the primary key generation type to Sequence and below is my dao.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        ">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="shutdown">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?rewriteBatchedStatements=true" />
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
        <property name="idleTimeout" value="200"/>
        <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="5"/>
        <property name="connectionTimeout" value="30000"/>
        <property name="validationTimeout" value="5000"/>
        <property name="initializationFailFast" value="true"/>
        <property name="maxLifetime" value="1800000"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="test-jpa"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="10"/>
                <entry key="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
                <entry key="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
                <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            </map>
        </property>
        <!--<property name="jpaProperties">-->
            <!---->
        <!--</property>-->
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
                <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
        <property name="defaultPersistenceUnitName" value="test-jpa"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

This enables single query to be executed every time. I am also flushing and clearing the entity manager accordingly.

Tech Stack: Spring 4, Hibernate 5.2.

Edit 1:
I have also gone through the below link but no luck
https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/

Edit 2:

I have followed the below link as well...but still no luck.

[JPA customize the JDBC batch size is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951366/jpa-customize-the-jdbc-batch-size-is-not-working)

datasource-proxy is printing the below log

Name:my-ds, Connection:2, Time:0, Success:True, Type:Prepared, Batch:False, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:0, Query:["insert into student (created_by, created_on, last_modified_on, version, name) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"], Params:[(test,2018-05-13 11:51:29.184,2018-05-13 11:51:29.184,0,Ashok Test 16)]

Answer (score 4):

When you are using the [`IDENTITY`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/) generator, Hibernate cannot use batching for INSERT statements. It can only batch UPDATE and DELETE statements.

Nevertheless, switching to [`TABLE`](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-never-use-the-table-identifier-generator-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) generator is even worse.

So, for MySQL, the only way to batch INSERT statements is if you generate the INSERT statements using JDBC.